# writing a recursion relation to a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, recursion

I have a recursion relation in the form of the following two equations:

$X_{t+1} = X_t + V_{t+1} \\
V_{t+1} = wV_t + cy(g-X_t)$

I want to write these two equations into a matrix form so that I can analyze using some Linear algebra techniques. the problem is, I cannot seem to write as a square matrix.

---

Here is my partial solution:

$X_{t+1} = X_t + wV_t + cy(g-X_t)\\
V_{t+1} = wV_t + cy(g-X_t)$

I will group all $X_t$ and $V_t$ together:

$X_{t+1} = (1-cy)X_t + wV_t + cyg \\
V_{t+1} = -cyX_t + wV_t + cyg$

If I set $g=0$, then this would come into a nice clean form as follows:

$X_{t+1} = (1-cy)X_t + wV_t \\
X_{t+1} = -cyX_t + wV_t$

So this can be written as follows:

$\begin{pmatrix} X_{t+1} \\ V_{t+1} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1-cy & w \\ -cy & w\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X_t \\ V_t\end{pmatrix}$

The matrix therefore would be easy to diagonalize, etc. But we made a simplying case when $g=0$. Can I still make this form for the case when $g \neq 0$? How can I change the matrix?

Thanks

Comment: Can we get some context? What is $g, y$ etc; why did you specify $g=0$. What's special about $g$?

Comment: Well $g$ is just a constant. Of course, a general $g$ would be nice to see, instead of setting it $g=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write
$$
\begin{pmatrix} X_{t+1} \\ V_{t+1} \\ 1\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1-cy & w & cyg \\ -cy & w & cyg \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}X_t \\ V_t \\ 1\end{pmatrix}
$$
This way you essentially have three sequences $X_t$, $V_t$ and $Z_t$, with $Z_t=1$ for all $t$. Now you can analyze their behaviour using this new recursive relation and the knowledge that $Z_t=1$.

Answer (score 3):

As slight variation, write $X_{t+1}$ and $V_{t+1}$ in terms of $X_t$ and $V_t$:

$$
X_{t+1} = X_t + w V_t - cy X_t  + cyg\\
V_{t+1} = wV_t -cyX_t + cgy
$$
notice that the term $cgy$ is independent of $t$, the relation is not a matrix relation, it is an *affine* recursive relation which can be written as:

$$
\left(\begin{array}{c} X_{t+1} \\ V_{t+1} \end{array}\right) = \left( \begin{array}{cc} (1-cy) & w \\ -cy & w \end{array} \right)\left(\begin{array}{c} X_t \\ V_t \end{array}\right) + \left(\begin{array}{c} cyg \\ cyg \end{array}\right)
$$
This is a relation of the type $Q_{t+1} = A Q_{t} + Y$ and can be solved by the change of variable to $Z_t= Q_t + \Lambda$ where the matrix $\Lambda$ is chosen to make the recursive relation a matrix relation (instead of affine), this is achieved by taking $\Lambda = - ({\bf 1} -A)^{-1} Y$, one gets:

$$
Z_{t+1} = A Z_{t} = A^{t}Z_1
$$

Comment: Hi, is the last statement supposed to mean: $Z_{t+1} = \Lambda Z_t$? (And not $A$?)

Comment: Hi, no it is indeed $A$, this is because $Z$ is $Q$ +  something, and two successive $Q$'s are related by an $A$ + something. The choice of $\Lambda$ is such that the "something" vanishes, leaving only an $A$ to connect two sucessive terms in the sequence.

Comment: Another term is "non-homogeneous linear recurrence", and it can also be solved by complimentary and particular solutions, just like the analogous system of first order linear ODEs.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think of it that way, but I see what you mean. Also, the term "non-homogeneous linear recurrence" seems also more appropriate, specially within algebra, while "affine" is closer to the geometrical context.

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y_t=[X_t,V_t]^T,A=\begin{pmatrix}1-cy&w\\-cy&w\end{pmatrix}$. Then $Y_{t+1}=AY_t+cyg[1,1]^T$. If $cyg=0$, then $Y_t=A^tY_0$.

Assume that $cyg\not=0$. Since $I-A$ is invertible, there is a unique fixed point $T$ s.t. $T=AT+cyg[1,1]^T$. Put $Z_t=Y_t-T$; then $Z_{t+1}=AZ_t$ and $Z_t=A^tZ_0$.